# Can make determine whether an environment variable is defined?

Tags: makefile, environment-variables, gnu-make

AFAICT, `ifdef` in `make` works only for variables defined in the Makefile.  Is there a way to check whether an environment variable is defined?

Comment: Not sure but... you might be looking for the [`origin` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Origin-Function)?

Comment: @G.M.  Looked it up and looks  very promising.  Will give it a shot tomorrow.  Thanks!

Comment: All variables from the environment are imported as make variables.  So `ifdef` works for environment variables as well.  You only need `origin` if you want to behave differently depending on whether the variable was defined in the environment vs. makefile vs. command line etc.

Comment: @MadScientist  Don't know what the deal is, but I tried and tried with `ifdef`.  Just would not give me anything.  `origin` gives me what I need.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you're doing (it's always best to include an actual example of what you have tried) but it definitely works:

```
$ cat Makefile
ifdef FOO
$(info FOO is defined)
endif
all:;@:

$ make

$ FOO=1 make
FOO is defined
```